# awk filter rows by column

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

This is my row.

```
2706 abc/efe/efefe/fefe 10143 fefef/dbddf/fvfvdf/vdfvdp 8927 fvdfv/fvdv/fvdfv/fvdfv 11546 fvsddfv/fdfvdv/fvddffv/fvddfv
```

expected output

```
2706 abc/efe/efefe/fefe  
10143 fefef/dbddf/fvfvdf/vdfvdp  
8927 fvdfv/fvdv/fvdfv/fvdfv  
.  
.  
.  
.  
11546 fvsddfv/fdfvdv/fvddffv/fvddfv
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? What did you try? What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the format of your row were fixed, you could give this line a try:

```
cat file|xargs -n2
```

Test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
2706 abc/efe/efefe/fefe 10143 fefef/dbddf/fvfvdf/vdfvdp 8927 fvdfv/fvdv/fvdfv/fvdfv 11546 fvsddfv/fdfvdv/fvddffv/fvddfv

kent$  cat f|xargs -n2 
2706 abc/efe/efefe/fefe
10143 fefef/dbddf/fvfvdf/vdfvdp
8927 fvdfv/fvdv/fvdfv/fvdfv
11546 fvsddfv/fdfvdv/fvddffv/fvddfv
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s' '{ORS=(NR%2?" ":"\n")}1' file
2706 abc/efe/efefe/fefe
10143 fefef/dbddf/fvfvdf/vdfvdp
8927 fvdfv/fvdv/fvdfv/fvdfv
11546 fvsddfv/fdfvdv/fvddffv/fvddfv
```

With some (most?) seds:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^ ]+ +[^ ]+) +/\1\n/g' file
2706 abc/efe/efefe/fefe
10143 fefef/dbddf/fvfvdf/vdfvdp
8927 fvdfv/fvdv/fvdfv/fvdfv
11546 fvsddfv/fdfvdv/fvddffv/fvddfv
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a newline after every sequence of number followed by a string of non-numeric characters:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]* [^0-9]*\) /\1\n/g' input
```

or replace the blank after a non-numeric character by a newline:

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]\) /\1\n/g' input
```

*Gives:*

```
2706 abc/efe/efefe/fefe
10143 fefef/dbddf/fvfvdf/vdfvdp
8927 fvdfv/fvdv/fvdfv/fvdfv
11546 fvsddfv/fdfvdv/fvddffv/fvddfv
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use sed,

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+\([0-9]\+\)/\n\1/g' file
```

Through grep,

```
grep -oP '\d+\s+\S+' file
```

Comment: somewhat more concise format of your answer: **`sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]([0-9]+)/\n\1/g' file`**

Comment: @slayedbylucifer sed in mac won't support `-r`